# how to iterate array of dictionary without loop using django?

Tags: python, django

This my scenario. I have 30 records in the array of dictionary in django. So, I tried to iterate it's working fine. but it takes around one minute. How to reduce iteration time.  I tried map function but it's not working. How to fix this and I will share my example code.

**Example Code**

```
def find_places():
    data = [{'a':1},{'a':2},{'a':3},{'a':4},{'a':5},{'a':6},{'a':7},{'a':8}]
    places =[]
    for p in range(1,len(data)):
        a = p.a
        try:
            s1 = sample.object.filter(a=a)
        except:
            s1 = sample(a=a)
            s1.save()
        plac={id:s1.id,
                a:s1.a}
        places.append(plac)
    return places

find_places()
```

I need an efficient way to iterate the array of objects in python without a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

You can create a list hen save it at once, try this:

```
def find_places():
    data = [{'a':1},{'a':2},{'a':3},{'a':4},{'a':5},{'a':6},{'a':7},{'a':8}]
    places =[]
    lst = []
    for p in data:
        a = p['a']
        lst.append(a)  # store it at once
```

Then try to store it into database. You can search: How to store a list into Model in Django.

I only made changes to loop of the code, if database side also fails you can let me know.

Comment: I checked my DB code it's working fine. I need only one How to iterate an array of dictionaries without loop. Is it possible?. because I checked DB data are showing correctly. execution time it's too long. How to reduce it.

Comment: you can try map or comprehensine but I dont expect much efficiency. It would be better if you use another data structure instead of list of dictionaries.

Comment: The reason it consumes a lot of time is database you save each time. You can collect all data in a list and save them at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter outside the loop and run `get_or_create` instead of reverting to an object creation if the filter doesn't match.

```
data_a = [d.a for d in data]
samples = sample.objects.filter(a__in=data_a)
places = []
for a in data_a:
    s1, created = samples.get_or_create(
        a=a
    )
    place = {id: s1.id, a:s1.a}
    places.append(place)
```